# Is there a better way to replicate field groups for each option in Code Igniter forms?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

It's been a while since I've used Code Igniter regularly - hoping a more seasoned user can help me out.

I'm adding a form to a CMS to allow the content editors to create event listings. On each event there's the usual type of fields: date, name, location, etc. But they now also want to list the different types of tickets available. Each ticket "type" has different data attached to it such as price, quantity available etc.

The editors require the ability to add multiple types of tickets to each event.

So essentially on the 'add' form I want to have:

Ticket Type [.....................................]

Price Per Ticket [.....]

Quantity Available [...]

Then a button to allow a new type to be added (all before saving the event record).

If building outside of CI I would normally do this using a Javascript function to replicate the fieldset, and use input names as arrays to allow the duplicates (the server side would then loop through each).

Is there a better way? Or anything specific to Code Igniter that I'm missing?

Comment: I'd expect someone with >1,000 rep points to know better than to add signatures to posts on SO. My own policy is not to remove sigs unless there's also other stuff to edit in the post, but others feel differently. I'd also expect someone with >1,000 rep points not to write titles in the format "Tag: Subject ... vague sort-of question".

Comment: Fair points - should have reviewed before posting. Thanks for the edits.